# C#: Handling Events inside a Class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, event-handling, mouseevent, picturebox

So I'm making a game (specifically Hearthstone) for my Programming II class because I have no better ideas. During my attempt, I realize that creating the Card interface would be much harder than I thought. The Card interface extends the PictureBox class like this:

```
Card : System.Windows.Form.PictureBox
```

Now, what I want to do is create an event for when the mouse clicks and releases the PictureBox. I know that the way to create the event requires the object sender and EventArgs e, but I'm not sure how to make it handle the actual event. For example, when I write the code

```
static void Play(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

I wish to have it handle the PictureBox's OnMouseUp event, but I have no idea what object to say it handles. I searched it up, but either I was using the wrong keywords and not finding the right thing or it hasn't been a post yet. Here's what I have now, and I'm not sure if it works; I haven't really gone around to testing it because I'm not in a computerized area this winter break:

```
static void Play(object sender, EventArgs e) handles Card.OnMouseUp {}
```

Where Card extends PictureBox. I wanted to use

```
handles sender.OnMouseUp
```

But I realized that it would not work as sender is a parameter (or would it). Anyways, thanks for your time for looking at this and I hope you guys can solve my problem.

Comment: By the way if any of the syntax is wrong I did this on my phone while I was away from the computer and Google Docs doesn't give me syntax errors except for the ones that occur in the English language.

Comment: It will be more better if you can post completely what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function to your Card class.  Whenever mouse up is called, it'll call your function too.

```
protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseUp(e);
            Play(this, e);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but where would I put it?

Comment: Completely changed it, should be more straightforward now.